# $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=L \in \mathbb{R} $

Tags: derivatives

let function $f$ at $x=a\in \mathbb{R}$ be  differentiable and $n ,m , k \in \mathbb{R}$

then prove that  : $$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+mh)-f(a+nh)}{kh}=\frac{m-n}{k}f'(a) $$

My Try :

since function $f$ at $x=a\in \mathbb{R}$ is  differentiable : So we have :

$$f'(a)=\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=L \in \mathbb{R} $$

Now : $x-a= h$ :

$$f'(a)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=L \in \mathbb{R} $$

Now what ?

Comment: $f(a+mh)-f(a+nh)=f(a+mh)-f(a)+f(a)-f(a+nh)$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+mh)-f(a+nh)}{kh} & = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+mh)-f(a)- \big(f(a+nh)-f(a)\big)}{kh} \\[5px]
& = \frac{m}{k} \, \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+mh)-f(a)}{mh} - \frac{n}{k} \, \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+nh)-f(a)}{nh}
\end{align}
$$